# Posting to a user's Facebook wall using Facebook Application Access Token fails

Tags: facebook

I simply follow the Facebook docs and try to publish to a Facebook user wall but its failing.
First I get my application's Facebook application access token using the following:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
Then using this app access token I try to post to a facebook user wall with the following:
https://graph.facebook.com/FB_USER_ID/feed?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&message=MY_MESSAGE

Now if instead of the **APP_ACCESS_TOKEN** I use **USER_ACCESS_TOKEN** it works! Message successfully gets posted on the user wall!!

I am sure it is possible to post to a user wall using APP_ACCESS_TOKEN. Please point out if I am somewhere going wrong!

(**Ref:**www.developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/)

Need help!! Would be very much grateful to you! :)

Comment: What error are you receiving? Do other calls with the app access token work?

Comment: Hey my problem got solved!! Now I am able to post to a Facebook user's wall on his/her behalf! I just had to read the response returned from Facebook! :)

Comment: Hey there Lavlove B.. Could you briefly explain what you did for posting using app access token because I have to do the same but after 2-3 days of R&D, I couldn't find anything useful. Any help would be really appreciated!